# Can another VPN client be used to connect to a network, OpenVPN is installed on?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect a computer by VPN. OpenVPN fails to install, it's corrupt. Is there an alternative VPN client that would work on Windows 7 that I can install?

I'm a little confused as I thought OpenVPN is more of a network protocol but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) OpenVPN it's the name of a specific VPN client program.

Comment: OpenVPN is very different to other VPN types. Much like PPTP is very different from L2TP or SSTP, for example. OpenVPN uses a non-standard protocol and ports, hence why you need a client to connect to an OpenVPN VPN.

Comment: @BigChris ok so what's a name of a client capable of connecting to OpenVPN that aside from this one? openvpn.net/index.php/download.html

Answer (score 1):

OpenVN is in general a protocol name, yet there are 2 famous clients (from the same company?) starting with OpenVPN:

1. OpenVPN UI
2. OpenVPN Connect

If you are using OpenVPN UI client (highly recommended), please consult [this guide](https://www.sumovpn.com/guides/win7/openvpn.html) for setup.

Comment: Unfortunately that link to the guide is down or gone. Any idea if OpenVPN UI is ok in Windows 10? OpenVPN Connect (ver 2.0.18.202) is using lots of CPU and I'd like to replace it.